# Does the HTC One X support GLONASS?

Tags: gps, tegra, htc-one-x

I'm looking to buy the brand new HTC One X (Tegra 3 version) but I want to know if it's compatible with GLONASS (Russian GPS satnav equivalent).

I already know that the Snapdragon S4 version supports it but does the Tegra 3 support it as well?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to find technical information on the Tegra 3, and I can't find a single mention of GPS capabilities.  Nor can I find anything specifically about the Tegra 3 One X's GPS capabilities.  I would guess that you're out of luck but it's difficult to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acccording to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1587452), it does NOT support GLONASS

They ran GPS tests on both [Galaxy Note](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/4d8f9b5b0dfa036f265c27d4ef13b148/4f8207ec/9/8/9/2/0/3/capture_04.jpg) and [HTC One X](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/d5351d561e8a7babc74e3d1c631aa437/4f8207ef/9/8/9/2/0/4/Screenshot_2012-04-07-21-13-48.jpg), the former of which does officially support GLONASS; and the former showed 2x the amount of detected satellites.

Comment: according to AnandTech's review, it does.

Comment: @Eshwar - you may want to post that as an answer with a quoute and some details, I'd be interested.

Comment: The number of detected satellites doesn't really tell you whether GLONASS is supported or not.  I can't find any information about the satellite ID numbers (SVNs) used for GLONASS, so I'm not sure if you could check whether any of the visible satellites are GLONASS.

Comment: yeah apprently it supports GLONASS (the hardware does) but it's not enabled so if someone finds a patch to enable it that would be great!

Comment: @DVK seems I was mistaken, the GLONASS support I read was for the Snapdragon SoC so not sure about the Tegra 3 version!